# Basis For $\mathrm{Im}(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $T(A)=\mathrm{trace}(A)$. Find a basis for $\mathrm{Im}(T)$.

On the one hand, $\mathrm{Im}(A)=t$ so $\mathrm{span}(t)=1$ and therefore the basis is $\{1\}$.  On the other hand, $\mathrm{Im}(A)=\mathrm{col}(T)$ but I can not see why $\dim(\mathrm{col}(T))=\mathrm{rank}(T)=1$.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to compute a basis for $\ker(T)$? The image is clearly $\mathbb{R}$. Note that the column space only makes sense for matrices, which $T$ isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you see that? The matrix of $\;T\;$ wrt the standard basis in $\;\Bbb R^{n\times n}\,,\,\,\Bbb R\;$ is

$$[T]=\left(1\;0\;0\;\ldots\;0\;1\;0\;\ldots\;1\right)\in R^{n^2}$$

with $\;1\,$-s in the places $\;1\,,\,n+2\,,\,2n+3\,,\,\;$ and etc. Clearly, $\;\dim(Col(T))=1\;$ ...

Comment: If we look at 2 by 2 case the span of $Im(T)$ is $\{e_1,e_e4\}$ where $e_1$ is matrix in the $(1,1)$ place and $e_4$ is matrix in the $(2,2)$ place?

Comment: @gbox The span of $\;\text{Im}\,T\;$ will **always** be the whole $\;\Bbb F\;$ whenever $\;T\;$ is **not** the zero linear functional !

Comment: So because we $T(A)=trace(A)$ every elementary basis element of $R^{n\times n}$ goes to $1$ the span of all of them is again $1$?

Comment: @gbox No: not "every" element of the standard basis goes to $\;1\;$, as you can easily check. But it is enough one single element goes to $\;1\;$ for the span of them all is the whole space $\;\Bbb F\;$ ,since this space's dimension is $\;1\;$ ...